# How to use PowerPoint Automation in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, powerpoint-automation

I get this error message when i try to open PowerPoint file (ppt) using Variant automation:

> Unknown Name

I tried using Automation:

```
// Open PPT File
void TMainForm::OpenPPTFile(UnicodeString APPTFile)
{

    UnicodeString ppt_path = ExtractFilePath(Application->ExeName)+"ppt\\";
    UnicodeString ppt_filename = ppt_path+APPTFile;
    Variant PowerPoint;

    if ( !DirectoryExists(ppt_path) )
    {
        Application->MessageBoxW(L"The specified Directory does't exist!", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    if ( !FileExists(ppt_filename) )
    {
        Application->MessageBoxW(L"The specified File does't exist!", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    PowerPoint = CreateOleObject("PowerPoint.Application");

    if ( PowerPoint.IsEmpty() )
    {
        Application->MessageBoxW(L"Unable to open Powerpoint, please check if installed!", L"Error", MB_OK);
        return;
    }

    PowerPoint.OlePropertySet("Enabled", true);
    PowerPoint.OlePropertySet("Visible", true);
    PowerPoint.OlePropertyGet("Presentations").OleProcedure("Open", ppt_filename, false, false, true);

}
```

This code gives me the error above.
**Note:** PowerPoint opens without any errors in the background, but the ppt doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when the property, function or method which you refer does not exist. `Application` object does not have `Enabled` property [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application). To open `ppt` you should use [`WideString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.WideString) type for `ppt_filename` because this type is compatible with `BSTR` type used with COM objects or you should use  [StringToOleStr()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.StringToOleStr).

Comment: @Jack I added information about string type used with COM objects in my answer. It may be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will use that.